# SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl() 2014.02 NOT working in FireFox35.0.1

Tags: javascript, firefox, sharepoint, spservices

I'm running into a very weird javascript issue that uses SPServices js library to get the current SharePoint list's name from site's url, which works perfectly in IE11 and Chrome(newest), but just stuck in FF(newest, 35.0.1).

Codes are simple. Any inputs would be welcome. Thanks much!!!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var siteURL = window.location.href.replace(/\/Lists.*/i, "");

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("before listId");           // successfully logged

        var listId = $().SPServices.SPListNameFromUrl();

        console.log(listId);                    // **NEVER gets hit!!! and NO any error or warning logged**
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that rather than using jquery.SPServices, there is another nice SharePoint extension "SharePointPlus.js" which works out the issue across all modern browsers e.g. IE11, FF35.0.1 and Chrome

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sharepointplus/3.0.9/sharepointplus.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $SP().lists(function(list) {
            for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) 
                if (decodeURI(window.location.pathname)===list[i]['Url']) {
                    var listName = list[i]['Name'];
                    //......
                }
        }
    }
</script>
```